# What is the simplest way to redirect users to different pages using a form (Bootstrap)?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, onchange

I have a form that asks two questions and therefore has 2 selections to be made, one is a dropdown list and the other radio buttons.

I want clicking the submit button to redirect the user to a certain webpage depending on the selections they make.

```html
<form>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="selectService">I am looking for assistance with</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="selectService">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="selectLearning">I want to recieve assistance for this service via</label>
        
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Written instruction</label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Video tutorials</label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">Live mentoring</label>
        </div>

    </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using both frontend and backend technologies.
the easiest way is to use javascript and pick the values of the options and radio buttons you can do that using

documents.getElementByClass and you will get both values store them in two separate variables and then you can use if else conditioning to select correct webpage to redirect and use location.href to redirect to respective page.